# Unix system("unzip archive.zip")

Tags: php, unix

When I call system("unzip archive.zip")
After extraction of a zip I get the status and extraction process at the top of page, How do I stop this from showing, and just extract silently.
[Here is a sample of the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WYyGw.png)

Comment: Note that you can also read a zip file this way: http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.compression.php *(without a system call)*

Comment: Well, I tried using the php libraries but didn't work. So I found an alternative to use the Unix, system(“unzip archive.zip”) function. And it resulted in this issue.

Comment: It's possible that the zip package for php isn't installed by default, in this case you can use port/apt/yum to install it. You can know what stream wrapper are installed on your system using: `var_dump(stream_get_wrappers());`

Comment: Well, actually I uploaded a zip file on a hosted server, and upon uploading I wanted to extract it. But using Zip Libraries failed so I used the Unix function, Thanks anyways. @CasimiretHippolyte

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try redirecting stdout and stderr:

`system("unzip archive.zip >/dev/null 2>&1")`

Comment: Thanks I'll try it out

Comment: Just tried it and it worked but am still getting _"Archive: uploads/95521-index.zip"_ part of the status.

Comment: Thanks, I just rechecked my code i didn't use it properly before.